# Re-escape brackets in PS1

Tags: bash, prompt, escape-characters

As [others](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/053) have pointed out, color codes in `PS1` should be bracketed by `\[` and `\]` to avoid them taking up horizontal space. I've added the necessary code to [`.bashrc`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/.bashrc):

```
highlight()
{
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ]
    then
        printf '\['
        tput bold
        printf '\]'
        printf '\['
        tput setaf $1
        printf '\]'
    fi
    shift
    printf -- "$@"
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ]
    then
        printf '\['
        tput sgr0
        printf '\]'
    fi
}

highlight_error()
{
    highlight 1 "$@"
}
```

The last function is used in `PS1` in both normal and escaped command substitutions to be able to change the string based on the result of the previous command:

```
# Exit code
PS1="\$(exit_code=\${?#0}
highlight_error \"\${exit_code}\${exit_code:+ }\")"

...

if [ "$USER" == 'root' ]
then
    PS1="${PS1}$(highlight_error '\u')"
else
    PS1="${PS1}\u"
fi
```

The issue is then that the escaped brackets are output as literals, so my prompt looks like this after running a command which doesn't exist:

```
\[\]\[\]127 \[\]user@machine:/path
$
```

Wrapping the escaped `highlight_error` in `printf %b` didn't help. How can I fix the output so that I can **use the functions for both normal and escaped command substitutions**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that any escape sequence actually in `PS1` literally needs to be wrapped in `\[` and `\]`, but if you call a function or command that produces output, it does not need to be wrapped.

So why not just move the

```
"\$(exit_code=\${?#0}
highlight_error \"\${exit_code}\${exit_code:+ }\")"
```

stuff inside a function, e.g.

```
print_error_if_error()
{
    exit_code=$?
    if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
        highlight_error "$exit_code "
    fi
}
```

and then I think you can remove all the `\[` and `\]` stuff...

```
highlight()
{
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ]
    then
        tput bold
        tput setaf $1
    fi
    shift
    printf -- "$@"
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ]
    then
        tput sgr0
    fi
}

highlight_error()
{
    highlight 1 "$@"
}

PS1='$(print_error_if_error)'

# ...

if [ "$USER" = 'root' ]
then
    PS1="${PS1}$(highlight_error '\u')"
else
    PS1="${PS1}\u"
fi
```

Comment: Aha, that explains why it's been working so far. Thanks!

Comment: Ouch, turns out this only works because of the `\n` in my `PS1`. If I remove it my input will overlap like before :(

Answer (score 0):

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592077/bash-prompt-and-echoing-colors-inside-a-function) for a solution using the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` variable. 
Write the name of a function in it which will be called every time before a new prompt is displayed. If you set `PS1` in that function, you can solve your problem and have color commands in functions:

```
# ... Using your highlight and highlight_error functions ...

prompt(){
    exit_code=${?}
    PS1="\u@\h \$ "
    if [[ $exit_code != 0 ]];then
        PS1="$(highlight_error "($exit_code)") $PS1"
    fi
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="prompt"
```